# sharing state between threads using LocalChannel in Netty 4

Tags: java, netty, multicast, channel, jgroups

I'm building a POC with Netty 4, just a basic client/server setup; my question is how to effectively share state across threads within the server process itself, let me explain...

### Server

The server is nothing fancy; standard logic for accepting remote connections using `boss` and `workers` event loop groups (code not shown).

#### Where it gets interesting

The server supports pluggable modules that provide metrics and group management services.  The modules run autonomously as child threads, periodically generating information important for the server to function properly; this is where I'm unsure what to do; how to get info produced from the thread modules *to* the server process in a "netty" way.

### Naive Approach

#### Local VM Channel

Looking at example [LocalEcho](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/localecho/LocalEcho.java), it appears [LocalChannel](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/local/LocalChannel.html) and [LocalServerChannel](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/local/LocalServerChannel.html) provides VM (in-memory) communication, though I was expecting such channels to be easier to set up, but here goes:

```
//in-memory server
EventLoopGroup serverGroup = new DefaultEventLoopGroup();

ServerBootstrap svm = new ServerBootstrap();
   svm.group(serverGroup)
     .channel(LocalServerChannel.class)
      .handler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalServerChannel>() {
         @Override
         public void initChannel(LocalServerChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
         }
      })
     .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalChannel>() {
         @Override
         public void initChannel(LocalChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast( EventsFromModule_Handler());
         }
      });

    //start server vm
    svm.bind(addr).sync();

//in-memory client
EventLoopGroup clientGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); 
Bootstrap cvm = new Bootstrap();
  cvm.group(clientGroup)
    .channel(LocalChannel.class)
    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<LocalChannel>() {
       @Override 
       public void initChannel(LocalChannel ch) throws Exception {
         ch.pipeline().addLast(
            new DefaultModuleHandler());
       }
     });
```

#### Connect Modules

Here's where I create and fork the modules; first I get a channel from the client vm, passing it to the module..

```
Channel mch = cvm.connect(addr).sync().channel();
ModuleFactory.fork( 
   new DiscoveryService( mch), 
   )
```

...now the module has a dedicated channel for generating events; such events will be handled by `EventsFromModule_Handler()`, bridging the gap between modules and the (server) process.

### Question

I'm very new to netty, but is using `LocalChannel`s in this context a valid approach?
Am I doing something entirely wrong?

Comment: I believe it is a valid approach. As long as the server knows what to do with such "internal" events, you can safely use this approach to generate independent sub modules. You can even manage the shutdown of them through a particular message sent by the sever, or manage specific requests from server to sub modules (so not only in passive way but active way). Some optimization could be done if necessary for instance by sharing the eventLoopGroup between the "network" server bootstrap and the "internal" server side bootstrap (and eventually but not necessary on client side too).

Comment: Thanks, @FredericBrégier, the only example I found for LocalChannel was from netty examples on Github; are you aware of any others? Regarding sharing eventloopgroups, I considered that too, but wasn't sure if it was valid, thx.

Comment: I m not sure there are many examples. I m using it personally to manage multiplexing (1 network connection for many single and independent streams or processes between 2 hosts) such that I minimize the connection's cost in favour of exchanges. Your approach is different (internal sub asynchronous processes) but I like the idea...

Comment: Just a short comment on eventLoopGroup usage, you can have a look on one of the presentation made by Norman on Netty, as this one : http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#18.0